# What is the sensor inside NIKON D3300?

Tags: nikon, sensor, nikon-d3300

Looking for a DSLR with Sony sensor inside, NIKON uses Sony EXMOR CMOS sensor in their DSLR. But there is no confirmation about what is the sensor used in NIKON D3300.

Comment: Why do you care about the manufacturer of the sensor, rather than the properties of the sensor?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/69462/1943

Comment: Sony sensor = Higher dynamic range, Also it will be easy to research about the properties of the said sensor if I know what make and model it is.

Comment: @M.G.Rashed You can't say "Sony sensor = Higher dynamic range" if you're not specifying what you compare it with and under what circumstances (what ISO for example). What problem are you trying to solve? What are you trying to capture?

Comment: Landscape is in my interest. Making a comparison in the link at the end, I find D3300 very promising (I can only buy entry level APS-C). That is why asked the question. Now can anybody please simply answer the question if they know the answer? - http://www.dxomark.com/Cameras/Compare/Side-by-side/Nikon-D5300-versus-Nikon-D3300-versus-Canon-EOS-70D___919_928_895

Comment: On "can someone please just answer the question", please read [PSA: Why is it important to provide apparently irrelevant details in a question?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/psa-why-is-it-important-to-provide-apparently-irrelevant-details-in-a-question)

Answer (score 3):

There is no definite answer to the question, unless anyone can find a teardown that shows the part number for the sensor.

Nikon use sensors from Aptina, Sony, Toshiba and their own designs, many of which offer excellent dynamic range at base ISO (on a par with Sony EXMOR). I suggest you look at test results for the D3300 on DXO mark and ignore the sensor manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, regardless of the sensor maker, NIKON D3X00  series performs excellent compared to the Mid-to-High range Canon (even though D3X00 is entry level).

Answer (score 1):

The sensor is Sony IMX-193-AQK.

This is like a year late. I was looking for the sensor's spec sheet, but never found it.

Reference:

- [List of all Nikon DSLR cameras and their sensor manufacturer/designer](https://nikonrumors.com/2015/12/16/list-of-all-nikon-dslr-cameras-and-their-sensor-manufacturerdesigner.aspx/) at nikonrumors.com.